# HaMiDeW coefficients - recursive calculation of the coincidence limits

Tags: quantum-field-theory, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, mathematical-physics, curvature

In his book [Aspects of Quantum Field Theory in Curved Spacetime](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139172073) Stephen Fulling calculates the coincidence limit $[a_1]$ and gives an idea of how $[a_n]$ with $2 ≤ n$ can be found recursively.

Since the calculation of $[a_2]$ is much more laborious than the calculation of $[a_1]$, I hope that it can be found in the literature. Some references would be welcome.

Comment: I’ve deleted my answer. I hope that someone else can help you more than I did.

Comment: @Filippo there is a book by SA Fulling where the procedure you are interested in is explained in some details. It is entitled Aspects of QFT in curved spacetime.

Comment: By the way, I suspect that the root of our argument over my now-deleted answer is that your paper (which I could not see) factors out $\mathscr D^{1/2}$ whereas my answer factored out $\Delta^{1/2}$. If you had provided sufficient information in your question, I would not have wasted an hour writing an answer that did not match what your paper does.

Comment: https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/aspects-of-quantum-field-theory-in-curved-spacetime/D96D902C0432D20FA5F0CC75C5E93FE6

Comment: @Ghoster I am sorry. But both my paper and your paper say that $a_0$ is defined by $\langle\mathrm d\sigma,\nabla a_0\rangle=0$ and $[a_0]=1$ and I don't think that $a_0\equiv 1$ is a solution. Here is another argument, that you may not like: In the language of mathematicians, we assume that we are given a vector bundle $E\to M$ and a generalized Laplacian $F\colon\Gamma(M,E)\to\Gamma(M,E)$ (there exist $\nabla$ and $P$ s.t. $F=\nabla^*\nabla+P$). Then it doesn't make sense to assume that $x\mapsto a_0(x,x')\in L(E_{x'},E_x)$ (defined on a neighborhood of $x'$) is constant.

Comment: (Since the fibers are disjoint.)

Comment: @Ghoster In any case I can guarantee that your support has been appreciated.

Comment: My answer was not suitable for gauge theories, where the Green function and the HaMiDeW coefficients are matrices. I had used this approach only with scalar fields, and the paper I linked to is about scalar fields. With gauge fields I agree that $a_0(x,x’)$ is not identically 1.

Comment: The [paper](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Heat_kernel_expansion_in_the_background_field_formalism) I originally linked to is for the more general case of gauge theory, which is why it has nonzero covariant derivatives for $a_0$ (determined by the fiber bundle curvature), in conflict with my answer.

Comment: Note to mods: Add banner after bounty is gone.